# La funcion ftp_connect no siempre funciona

Tags: php, ftp

como estan? Estoy con el siguiente problema:
Tengo un script PHP donde me conecto a un FTP para subir un archivo, el problema es que cuando se ejecuta por primera vez, me devuelve un error donde falló la conexión, y si lo vuelvo a ejecutar al rato, conecta y sube el archivo de forma correcta.
Es un FTP, puerto 21 y tiene 3600 de timeout.
Alguna idea/solución?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Podrias mostrar el codigo que tienes para poder ayudarte?

Comment: @JoséBardales Es tan simple como un ftp_connect($host,21,3600). Luego si conecta hago el ftp_login

Comment: Es necesario que edites tu pregunta @Alan esto para que la reestructures bien y la gente pueda ayudarte con facilidad, agregando el código que tienes y lo que has intentado. Con esto evitas malas calificaciones y una mejor respuesta.